# Python Modules Only Installing For Python 2

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to python and want to start doing some more advanced programming in python 3. I installed some modules using pip on the terminal (I'm using a mac) only to find out that the modules only installed for python 2. I think that it's because I only installed it to the python 2 path, which I think is because my system is running python 2 by default.

But I have no idea how to get around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `pip3`. OS X will default to Python 2 otherwise.

Comment: actually if u do a pip upgrade in pip3, it will replace the default pip

Comment: pip2 and pip3 are likely on the same `PATH`, so changing `PATH` won't help.

Answer (score -1):

When creating your virtual environment (you are using a virtual environment, right?) use `pyvenv <foo>` instead of `virtualenv <foo>`, and that will create a Python 3 virtual environment, free of Python 2. Then you are free to use `pip` and it will install the modules into that venv.